# $f[a_1] = G$ means $a_1 \subseteq f^{-1}[G]$ for functions on metric spaces?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, proof-explanation

The theorem/proof:

[image]

**Question**

The part that I don't under stand is the red underlined bit.

What I understand:

let $a_1,a_2$ be sets s.t $a_1 \oplus a_2 = A$ and let $f[a_1] = G$ and let $f[a_2] = H$.
This works because $G$ and $H$ are disjointed.

But then $A = U\cup V$ (thanks to the "$A\cap $" and the way $U$ and $V$ are defined in the proof)suggests that $a_1 \subseteq f^{-1}[G]$ and $a_2 \subseteq f^{-1}[H]$

But how can we just assume this? Is it not possible to have $U\cup V \neq A$? {eg: $ f^{-1}[G] \subset a_1 $}

Comment: If $x\in A$, then $f(x) \in f(A)=G \cup H$, so either $f(x) \in G$ or $f(x) \in H$, so either $x \in A \cap f^{-1}(G)=U$ or $x \in A \cap f^{-1}(H)=V$. So $x \in U \cup V$, so $A \subset U \cup V$. The reverse inclusion being immediate, one has $A = U \cup V$.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Thank you for your replay. Is it accurate to say that if $f(A) = K$ then $ A \subseteq f^{-1}(K)$? is this a property of inverse functions? I see that it is necessary for $x \in f^{-1}(G)$

Comment: Yes. Indeed, if you take $x \in A$, then $f(x) \in f(A)$, so $f(x) \in K$, so $x \in f^{-1}(K)$. This proves that $A \subseteq f^{-1}(K)$.